# How to copy SSL certificate from a certificate authority to EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, openssl

I am trying to [create dev-endpoint server on EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-notebook-server-considerations.html). I must copy my SSL certificate key store onto the Amazon EC2 instance

```
scp -i ec2-private-key keystore.jks ec2-user@dns-address-of-ec2-instance:~/keystore.jks
```

I followed [ssl-certificate](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self) tutorial.
How should my scp line look like?

```
scp -i  server.key server.cert ec2-user@my....
```

Comment: can you check `man scp`? there is no such `scp -I` you can rearrange the`scp` command to `scp -i yourkey.pem server.*  ec2-user@my..`

Comment: @Adiii The question is what is actually  your key.pem? The one I generated with Openssl, or the one I had before,keygen(id_rsa,id_rsa.pub).

Comment: No, the one you download from aws during instance creation, seems like this -`ec2-private-key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following command:

```
scp -i $EC2_PEM $FILE $USERNAME@$REMOTE_HOST_ADDRESS:~/$PATH_TO_REMOTE_LOCATION
```

In this the following is what to use for the variables:

- `$EC2_PEM` - The PEM for connecting to the server (what you would use to SSH)
- `$FILE` - The name of the file (private key/public key), providing the full path (either absolute or relative) to the SSL on your current host machine
- `$USERNAME` - The username used to SSH to the remote host
- `REMOTE_HOST_ADDRESS` - Either the IP address or domain name of the server you are attempting to SCP the file to
- `$PATH_TO_REMOTE_LOCATION` - The path that the file will live on disk

You will need to run this for each file individually.