# How to install SSL Certificate on AWS EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I posted question yesterday [How to copy SSL to EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62815134/how-to-copy-ssl-certificate-from-a-certificate-authority-to-ec2). This is what I am supposed to do:

```
You can connect to your Zeppelin notebook using an HTTPS URL. This requires a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificate on your Amazon EC2 instance. The notebook server must provide web browsers with a certificate to validate its authenticity and to allow encrypted traffic for sensitive data such as passwords.
If you have an SSL certificate from a certificate authority (CA), copy your SSL certificate key store onto the Amazon EC2 instance into a path that the ec2-user has write access to, such as /home/ec2-user/.
```

I copied server.crt but I can not make connection from my Mac OS to ec2 instance.
I will repeat the steps:

1. Generated a private key and certificate signing request

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:x -out server.pass.key 2048
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

2. Generated a self-signed SSL certificate

```
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

My next steps:

```
scp -i sparktest.pem server.crt ec2-34-245-107-45.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

 ssh -i sparktest.pem ec2-34-245-107-45.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

milenko@ec2-34-245-107-45.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).

EC2 was created with Cloudformation.
[image]

Why I got permission denied?
What should I check?

Comment: You should use `ec2-user@ec2-34-245-107-45.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`; without `ec2-user`, it will log in as your local username, which is presumably not what you want.`

Comment: Yeah,work fine,post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a username for the destination.

Instead of having just `ec2-ip-address.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`, you need `ec2-user@ec2-ip-address.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` (in both `ssh` and `scp` commands).`

Without `ec2-user`, it will log in as your local username, which is not what you want!

Answer (score 1):

The permission denied could be a number of reasons check the following:

- The sparktest.pem file has a public key added to the authorized_keys folder. This will be added automatically if this is the key attached to your instance
- The pem is for the user you’re trying to connect to on the host. You appear to be trying to connect to a user name milenko.
- The permissions of the key should be 400 with the user you’re running the command as, as the current user.